# SwiftUI - Value of type 'Text' has no member 'color' Error

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-form

I'm Getting Error in Swift UI Code That 
1)Protocol type 'Any' cannot conform to 'View' because only concrete types can conform to protocols
2)Value of type 'Text' has no member 'color'

Can anyone find the Solution?

[image: Here is Image What Actual issue is]

Comment: Don't post image of the code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is No such a modifier as `color()`. Use `foregroundColor()`:

```
Text("Hello world")
    .foregroundColor(.red)
```